# How can I get a certificate for a smart device application in windows mobile?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Does anybody knows how to get a certificate for a windows mobile application? I'm using a testing certificate to install my application on a windows mobile device, but I want to publish my app too, so I don´t know how to get a certificate because the M2M program (wich is the Application Certification Program) doesn't exist anymore. 
Any idea or suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could call Verisign and purchase a PFX. But, if you're okay with self signing a certificate, then you can just make one yourself.

see:

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12460/Sign-Code
2. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsmobile/archive/2006/01/28/making-a-root-cert-cab-file.aspx

Then, set up a post-build step for your project like this:

```
"$(SolutionDir)Installer\signtool.EXE" sign /f "$(SolutionDir)certificates\my_company.pfx" /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll "$(ProjectDir)obj\$(ConfigurationName)\*.exe"
"$(SolutionDir)Installer\cabwiz.exe" "$(SolutionDir)Installer\my_company.$(ConfigurationName).inf" /prexml "$(SolutionDir)certificates\my_company.prexml.xml" /cpu arm
```

Now you will have a cab file installer that will install your self-signed certificate and self-signed executable(s).